# Spring-Kafka: How to pass the kafka topic from the application.yml

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a small project in Spring Kafka
I wish I could pass my kafka topic from application.yml and avoid a hard-coding problem. For the moment I have this situation:

```
public class KafkaConsumer {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;


    @KafkaListener(topics = "myTopic")
    public void listen(@Validate UserDto userDto) {

        User user= new User(userDto);
        userRepository.save(userDto.getAge(), user);
    }
}
```

at this moment I have the static kafka topic (being a string) is it possible to put it in the application.yml and have it read from there? Thanks everyone for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can post your topic in the application.yml :

```
kafka:
  template:
    default-topic: "MyTopic"
```

In your KafkaListerner :

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${spring.kafka.template.default-topic}'}")
```

So you should solve the problem of the "Attribute Value" failing to take a dynamic value

This worked for me.

Comment: You don't need SpEL for a simple placeholder - `@KafkaListener(topics = "${spring.kafka.template.default-topic}")` will work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use below entry in application.yml file

[image]

Usually we use @Value as below to pick data from properties/yaml files for a specified key in you Java class as below.

```
@Value("${kafka.topic.name}")
private String TOPIC_NAME;
```

Since Kafka Listener expects constant here, you can use directly as below

```
public class KafkaConsumer {

@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;


@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.name}")
public void listen(@Validate UserDto userDto) {

    User user= new User(userDto);
    userRepository.save(userDto.getAge(), user);
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried to use it but when I try to put the KafkaListerner it tells me "Attribute Value must be constant", is there anything else I should add?

Comment: Just use placeholder directly `@KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.name}")`.